# Why can't I declare a private member of a file-local type in another class within the same file?

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

This code:

```
public class Class1
{
    private Class2 _class2;

    private void Something()
    {
        Class2 class2;
    }
}

file class Class2
{

}
```

produces compiler error CS9051 on the member `_class2` but not on the local variable `class2` inside the method:

> File-local type 'Class2' cannot be used in a  member signature in
> non-file-local type 'Class1'.

Clicking on [the link provided with CS9051 opens this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/sorry-we-don-t-have-specifics-on-this-csharp-error?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS9051)), which at the time of this writing states **Sorry, we don't have specifics on this C# error**.  I couldn't find anything else on the web which explains why this is the case.  Can someone please explain why I *can* use `Class2` inside of a method or property within `Class1` but *not* as a private class member?  It seems like this reduces the usefulness of an otherwise-useful feature (the `file` access modifier).

Comment: Just checking: `Class1` isn't a `partial` class or anything like that?

Comment: I presume that having the variable as a private member makes it accessible to the outside world via reflection, whereas a variable inside a method cannot escape.

Comment: ["Why" is not a good question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/5133585) Please clarify what kind of answer you are expecting.

Comment: @Sweeper Something like "the reason for this is ______"

Comment: @MarcGravell No, I created that MCVE as is for this question.

Comment: Okay, so "the reason for this is that that's how file-local types are designed to work". Does that satisfy you? If it doesn't, and I'll repeat this again, please clarify what kind of answer you are expecting.

Comment: @Sweeper Can you stop being pedantic?  If you want, you go ahead and edit my question.  I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: I am not being pedantic. Your question is just unclear to me. So as I asked, does ["because that is how it is designed"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/file-local-types#usage-in-signatures) satisfy you?

Answer (score 1):

The proposal says [Only allow signature usage in members of file-local types](https://learn.microsoft.com/En-Us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/file-local-types#only-allow-signature-usage-in-members-of-file-local-types). There is also an example showing your use case.

A workaround is to type the fields as `object` and to cast the field when using it:

```cs
public class Class1
{
    private object _class2 = new Class2();

    private void Something()
    {
        Class2 class2 = (Class2)_class2;
    }
}

file class Class2
{

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Permit a file modifier on top-level type declarations. The type only exists in the file where it is declared.

https://learn.microsoft.com/En-Us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/file-local-types

Comment: Both the classes in the example code are in the same file.